# yahoo finance apis is out of order?

Tags: yql

Below api doesn't work, before 2 days ago.
that is yahoo finance open api.

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%3D%22USDKRW%22&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&format=xml&diagnostics=true
```

the api response below
is there anybody how can i found the table of yahoo.finance.xchange 
please?

```
<error xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:lang="en-US">
```

Failed to read from storage: store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys: Invalid store url: store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys


Failed to read from storage: store://RjdEzitN2Hceujh3tGHPj6: Invalid store url: store://RjdEzitN2Hceujh3tGHPj6


No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.xchange

Comment: The URL works for me.

Comment: No, it is not working. The results are empty. Do let me know if any solution was found.